# Cannot convert Oracle String to Date with dbplyr in R

Tags: r, database, oracle, time, dbplyr

After connecting to an oracle database, I want to summarize data per day. I am extracting the data with the tbl() function. The connection runs via RJDBC. The date column is stored as char.

The Date String looks like this (containing also times): 
    "2015-01-31 10:56:52.0"

I am trying to convert the string into date format:

```
melds <- bibu %>%
  select(DATE) %>%
  mutate(Datday = as.Date(to_date(substr(DATE, 1, 10))))
```

Running this Code, I would expect the string (chr) to be converted to Date. What happens is, that the string is cut properly to the date, but the times stay as 0s ("2015-01-31 00:00:00.0"). The column also remains in char format (and not date as expected).

Here the created sql query:

```
melds %>% show_query()
<SQL>
SELECT "DATE", CAST(to_date(SUBSTR("DATE", 1, 10)) AS DATE) AS "Datday"
FROM (TXYZ)
```

UPDATE AFTER QUESTION BELOW:

```
melds <- bibu %>%
  select(DATE) %>%
  mutate(Datday = as.Date(to_date(substr(DATE, 1, 10), "yyyy-MM-dd")), "%Y-%m-%d")

melds %>% show_query()
<SQL>
SELECT "DATE", CAST(to_date(SUBSTR("DATE", 1, 10), 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS DATE) AS "Datday", '%Y-%m-%d' AS """%Y-%m-%d"""
FROM (TXYZ)
```

ERROR: Unable to retrieve JDBC result set

Comment: did you ever figure out an answer to this? I've been struggling with this issue for a while now. I can use extract() to break down the pieces of the datetime field from Oracle SQL, but I have to make them into a character and then into a date, and it's too slow with the data that I am querying.

Comment: no, unfortunately not. I now usually directly send sql queries via python and rarely use dplyr....

Answer (score 1):

to convert string to date you should specify a format

```
to_date(SUBSTR("DATE", 1, 10),'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

or with time

```
to_date("DATE",'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

**Example:**

```
select  to_date(SUBSTR('2015-01-31 10:56:52.00', 1, 10),'yyyy-mm-dd') as dat
,to_date(substr('2015-01-31 10:56:52',1,19),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as datTime
,to_timestamp('2015-01-31 10:56:52.0','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.FF1')  as timestmp

from dual;
```

**Result:**

> ```
> DAT       | DATTIME   | TIMESTMP                    
> :-------- | :-------- | :---------------------------
> 31-JAN-15 | 31-JAN-15 | 31-JAN-15 10.56.52.000000000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f7cf7fd7c8e72366f93382fec8211d23)*

Comment: I tried that, but the date format got corrupted ("0031-15-01 00:00:00.0"). Moreover the coltype stayed chr.

Comment: i can't reproduce your Problem, because if i execute the statemens in the database i get the expected results. i have added examples.

Comment: I tried your suggestion with a date format. The SQL-Code got messed up, so I do not think it's a database problem, but a dbplyr interface issue.